# Method overriding in Java- assigning child class object to parent class variable

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

```
class Person{
    String name;

    void show(){
        System.out.println("I am parent");
    }
}

class  Student extends Person{
    String dit;

    void show(){
        System.out.println("I am child");
    }
}

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p;
        p = new Student();

        p.name = "Kamal";
        p.dit = "DIT/10/c1/1234"; // I'm not allowed to do this 
        p.show(); // Here in overriding child class method is called
    }
}
```

I am confused. As I understood 'p' variable cannot access dit (even though it is assigned with Student) because data type of p is Person which is parent class. Therefore parent class cannot access child class attributes and methods. But in overriding it calling child class method.

I am new to java. Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Runtime polymorphism

Comment: That's exactly what "overriding" means

Comment: The main thing you need to understand is that the variable `p` is of type `Person`, and the object referred to by `p` is of type `Student`.

Comment: If you need to access `p.dit`, then you should declare `Student p`. Not every `Person` has a `dit` which is why the compiler is preventing you from accessing the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **runtime polymorphism**.

**JVM** decides at runtime which method to call based on the **content** of the object **not the type** of object.

You cannot obviously access `dit`, because simply the type of object doesnt support that. `show` method is accessible because that is part of both parent and child class

More details [here](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-runtime-polymorphism-in-java/16)

Here is a classic example

```
class Animal {
  void whoAmI() {
    System.out.println("I am a generic Animal.");
  }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
  void whoAmI() {
    System.out.println("I am a Dog.");
  }
}
class Cow extends Animal {
  void whoAmI() {
    System.out.println("I am a Cow.");
  }
}
class Snake extends Animal {
  void whoAmI() {
    System.out.println("I am a Snake.");
  }
}

class RuntimePolymorphismDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal ref1 = new Animal();
    Animal ref2 = new Dog();
    Animal ref3 = new Cow();
    Animal ref4 = new Snake();
    ref1.whoAmI();
    ref2.whoAmI();
    ref3.whoAmI();
    ref4.whoAmI();
  }
}
The output is

I am a generic Animal.
I am a Dog.
I am a Cow.
I am a Snake.
```

Answer (score 0):

At **runtime** Java realizes that `p` is actually a `Student`, and it sees that `Student` has overrided `show()`, so it calls the `show` method in `Student` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability access members of a subclass from its parent.
In your case, if you want to access the dit variable you have to cast p object to Student.

```
((Student)p).dit = "DIT/10/c1/1234";
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't defined class Person. Your trying to create a new object (p) then attempting to define name but have no setters or getters.

```
class Person{
String name;

public Person( string name ){
    setName; }

public void setName(){this.name = name: }

public void getName(){ return name; }

    void show(){
        System.out.println("I am parent");
    }
}

class  Student extends Person{
    String dit;

public void setDit() {this.dit = dit; }

public void getDit() { return dit; }

    void show(){
        System.out.println("I am child");
    }
}
```

So you need to build fields for what you want to set and you need to add constructors for your objects you want to create/define. Hope this helps